# volume of a rectangular box

Tags: calculus

We are tasked with constructing a rectangular box with a volume of $15$ cubic feet:

1. The material for the top costs $12$ dollars per square foot.
2. The material for the $4$ sides costs $3$ dollars per square foot.
3. The material for the bottom costs $11$ dollars per square foot.

To the nearest cent, what is the minimum cost for such a box ?.

I tried to solve this problem but I just dont know how to set it up, I tried to do
$$
15 = 12x^{2} + 11x^{2} + \left(4 \times 3 \times x\times {15 \over x^{2}}\right)
$$
but I couldn't get the right answer from there.

Can anyone help walk me through whether I messed up setting up the problem or am I just solving it wrong ?.

I got $1.58$ so can someone show me what they got ?.

Comment: The given equation equates volume (15) to cost...

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.**  You wrote down the cost, but then you equated it with $15$.  The *volume* is $15$; you should simply write the cost $C(x)$ as a function of $x$:

$$
C(x) = 12x^2+11x^2+\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot x \cdot 15}{x^2} = 23x^2+\frac{180}{x}
$$

and then find the value of $x$ that minimizes $C$.  Find an expression for $C'(x)$ and then set $C'(x) = 0$.  This will be an equation in $x$; you should then find a solution that is a minimum of $C(x)$ (rather than a maximum).

Comment: Does the cost not depend on the other two dimensions of the *rectangular* box?

Comment: hey thanks a lot, I was on the right step, I had found the derivative and set it equal to zero and solved for x but i forgot to plug it back into my original equation.

Comment: @DJohnM: Well, one of the dimensions is taken care of by the fact that the volume equals $15$.  For the other, I am using (as I assume the OP is using) the fact that a square has the maximum area for a rectangle of given perimeter.  Making the three dimensions all unequal would be suboptimal.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I actually just copied the equation from the OP, but it looks right to me.  Did I miss something?  (Wouldn't be the first time!)  The height of a (box) side is $15/x^2$, the width is $x$, the cost per square foot is $3$ dollars, and there are four sides.  No? ¶ Yes, the fact that the base is square is not given, but it seems trivial. The OP appears to assume it (correctly). If it's useful, I could add a justification for it.